# Converting antiquated string date values to datetime values in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, date, datetime

I am trying to modernize an existing parcel data set that stores date information as strings in the following format: "YYYY MMM DD" 12/13/2022 would be stored as "2022 DEC 13."

Is there a way to do this within the field calculator?

I have tried using the convert time field tool to no avail. The legacy format for storing date data is atrocious.

Comment: Is this for display or are you trying to change the data?

Comment: I am trying to change the data

Comment: I setup a test data set, and was able to type into the convert time field tool, your string pattern, and convert it into a date. I did this in both arcpro and arcmap. What is the issue that you are seeing on your end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below expression in the Field Calculator:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(!original_field!, '%Y %b %d')
```

This expression uses the datetime.datetime.strptime() method to convert the date strings in the original field to date objects. The %Y %b %d part of the expression specifies the format of the date strings in the original field (i.e. "YYYY MMM DD").

Comment: Thanks Viv, this code should work--any suggestions about how to skip over values that do not meet the specified format? ex: if a value only has YYYY?

Comment: Yes, you can use the try and except keywords in the field calculator expression to handle any date strings that do not match the expected format.

Answer (score 0):

The following Python function works provided you do not have any values in the string field that cause it to fail (ex not having a month and date)

```
from datetime import datetime

def convert_date_string_to_datetime(date_string: str) -> datetime:
    # First, we parse the date string using the strptime() method,
    # which converts a string to a datetime object according to a
    # specified format. In this case, the format is "YYYY MMM DD",
    # where YYYY is the year (e.g. 2020), MMM is the abbreviated
    # month name (e.g. Jan), and DD is the day of the month (e.g. 01).
    date_datetime = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y %b %d")

    # Finally, we return the resulting datetime object.
    return date_datetime
```

Looks like I will need to clean the data or alter the script so that it skips over values that would cause it to fail.